# Guardar mas de un registro de una consulta

Tags: php

Tengo una consulta en la que puede variar el numero de datos recibidos, pero no se cómo hacerlo había pensado en una array, pero claro cuando va a salir los siguientes datos lo sobrescribe 
¿ Cómo podría guardar esos datos y luego mostrarlos en una tabla?

```
public function listarHistorial($id_usuario){

                    $sql = "SELECT ofertas_empleo.id_oferta, titulo, empresa, email_empresa, sector, localidad, historial.fecha_inscripcion 
                    FROM ofertas_empleo INNER JOIN historial ON ofertas_empleo.id_oferta=historial.id_oferta WHERE historial.id_usuario = ? ;";

                            $result = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                            $result->bind_param('i',$id_usuario);
                            $result->execute();
                            $result->bind_result($id,$titulo,$empresa,$email,$sector,$localidad,$fecha);
                            $result->fetch();

                            $datos = array($id,$titulo,$empresa,$email,$sector,$localidad,$fecha);

                            return $datos;

                            $result->close();
                            $this->conn->close();
                }
```

Esto es lo que intente con la solución

```
while($result->fetch()){
     $datos[] = array($id,$titulo,$empresa,$email,$sector,$localidad,$fecha);
   };
```

Comment: debes recorrer los resultados de la consulta, e ir asignandolos a un array. luego, ese array puedes ir acumulandolo en otro array. en tu caso, podrias hacer el $datos[] = array(), para asignar dinamicamente el tamaño. Por cierto, tu result-close y this-conn-close no funcionan, ya que haces el return antes.

Comment: Una duda, imagina que se requeriría 200 arrays por decir un numero, eso no sería contraproducente para el rendimiento de la página?

Comment: depende de tus datos. Normalmente 200 no es problema. Sin embargo, lo suyo es utilizar paginaciones en las consultas. Revisa usar LIMIT en ellas.

Comment: He intentado poner lo que me has dicho no sé si entendi mal    while($result->fetch()) {  $datos[] = array($id,$titulo,$empresa,$email,$sector,$localidad,$fecha);} Pero esto me da un error   que me dice que lo estoy convirtiendo a string